# capture pid of tomcat to kill using bash script in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, tomcat, putty

I am trying to write a bash script that finds the `PID` of tomcat6, kills it, starts it again, then waits 1 minute, then kills the process again and starts it again.

This is what I have so far but I am struggling to have the script kill tomcat using the previous pid:

```
ps aux | grep tomcat6
kill -9 $!
service Tomcat6 start
sleep 1m
ps aux | grep tomcat6
kill -9 $!
service Tomcat6 start
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have `pgrep` available?

Comment: im not sure what that is. im not very linux-savvy

Comment: `$!` is not appropriate here, as 1) you are not starting anything in the background, so it might have a tendency to be empty and 2) even if it isn't empty, it doesn't somehow magically contain the value from a particular field of the output of the previous command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
T_PID=$(ps aux | grep Tomcat6 | awk 'NR==1{print $2}')

kill -9 $T_PID

service Tomcat6 start
sleep 1m
```

If grep gives multiple outputs, NR==x will only get the PID of desired line.

Comment: this is what I get:kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
pkill tomcat6
```

Comment: I do appreciate the effort, really. But I can't use restart it does not work properly (tomcat6) so that is why I need to use kill and then start. My issue is that when I do "ps aux | grep tomcat6" it shows 2 pid's so I need the next line in the script to kill both processes. Any suggestions? That is why I put my base code I felt like it did a better job of pseudocoding the task. Thanks

Comment: @user3752761 And what happened when you tried to `pkill tomcat6`?

Answer (score 0):

To do it only one time it's enough (if you need sudo).

```
 sudo service tomcat6 restart ; sleep 1m ;  sudo service tomcat6 restart ;
```

or even better

```
 sudo /bin/bash -c "service tomcat6 restart; sleep 1m; service tomcat6 restart;"
```

---

This can be a never ending loop that you have to interrupt by hands.
Take it like a scratch.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do  
    pkill tomcat6  # or pkill -9 tomcat6 
    service tomcat6 start
    sleep 1m
done
```

If I remember well it exists the possibility to restart that service. 
If so you can use even

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do  
    service tomcat6 restart
    sleep 1m
done
```

Comment: i dont want it to be a never ending loop and it also says that it doesnt recognize the service Tomcat6.

Comment: Maybe is `tomcat6` and not `Tomcat6` ?

Comment: I do appreciate the effort, really. But I can't use restart it does not work properly (tomcat6) so that is why I need to use kill and then start. My issue is that when I do "ps aux | grep tomcat6" it shows 2 pid's so I need the next line in the script to kill both processes. Any suggestions? That is why I put my base code I felt like it did a better job of pseudocoding the task. Thanks.